# How to do 3 part if statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

Why the if statements doesn't work at the below?
I just want if the values are number do the math, if the values are string except "Done" give me just "enter a number" warning and continue, if the value is "Done" finish the job and give me the answers.

```
quantity = 0
sum = 0
avg = 0
n = None


while n != "Done":
    try:
        n = int(input("Enter a value:\n"))
        sum = sum + n
        quantity = quantity + 1
        avg = sum / quantity
    except:
        print("Enter a number!")

        if n =="Done":
            print("Process is Done!")
            break
            print("Sum : {}, Quantity : {}, Avg : {}".format(sum, quantity,avg))
```

Comment: Why do you need a try/except block here?

Comment: As I'm reading this, it seems highly unlikely that the "except" block will ever be executed because the 'try' block doesn't seem to be very error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n = int(input("Enter a value:\n"))`

Once you hit an Exception for invalid input for your `int()` cast, the "Done" value is never assigned to `n`. So, `n == "Done"` is effectively using the old value of `n` from the previous iteration or `None` if it's the first iteration.

Try the following:

```
quantity = 0
sum = 0
avg = 0
n = None
input_val = None

while input_val != "Done":
    try:
        input_val = input("Enter a value:\n")
        n = int(input_val)
        sum = sum + n
        quantity = quantity + 1
        avg = sum / quantity
    except:
        print("Enter a number!")

print("Process is Done!")
print("Sum : {}, Quantity : {}, Avg : {}".format(sum, quantity,avg))
```